# How to pass an abstract class as function parameter, which will then be used after the original goes out of scope?

Tags: c++, reference, abstract-class

I have the following abstract class

```
struct Interface {
    virtual ~Interface() = default;
    virtual void Do() = 0;
};
```

And I have one or more concrete class which implements `Interface`

```
struct ImplA final: Interface{
    virtual void Do() override {printf("DO IN ImplA\n");}
};

struct ImplB final: Interface{
    virtual void Do() override {printf("DO IN ImplB\n");}
};
```

Here is my main code (it is just abstracted away)

```
int main() {
    {
        ImplA implA{};
        Method(implA);
        ImplB implB{};
        Method(implB);
       // Goes out of scope
    }
    // some other stuff here
    return 0;
}
```

Here is what Method looks like
I used a global container to show that it lives outside of the scope of the Method as well. They will be used at a later time

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Container>> containers;
void Method(Interface& myInterfaceReference) {
    // to show that it lives out of scope of this method
    // how should the reference be passed to Container class
    // such that it can be used even after original instances are out of scope
    containers.emplace_back(new Container());
}
```

Finally what container class looks like. ←This is the part I am having difficulty with and open to all ideas as to how to design it.

```
struct Container {
    // I dont mind if it is newly created
    Interface& referenceToInterface;
    // What to do with the ctor, how to pass it
    Container(???) {}
    
    void UseInterface() {
    //Do Stuff with referenceToInterface
    }   
};
```

Comment: You probably need a `clone` virtual function.

Comment: @Jarod42, Thank you very much for your answer. Could you possibly give me some example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store a smart pointer within `Container` so that it controls the lifetime of the referred object:

```
struct Container {
    std::unique_ptr<Interface> pointerToInterface;
```

> ```
> // What to do with the ctor, how to pass it
> ```

Pass a smart pointer:

```
Container(std::unique_ptr<Interface> i)
    : pointerToInterface(std::move(i)) {}
```

> How to pass an abstract class as function parameter, which will then be used after the original goes out of scope?

Pass a smart pointer:

```
std::vector<Container> containers;
void Method(std::unique_ptr<Interface> i) {
    containers.emplace_back(std::move(i));


Method(std::make_unique<ImplA>());
Method(std::make_unique<ImplB>());
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, in this case, I should be `new` ing ImplA and ImplB instead of automatically creating them on stack?

Comment: @HasanEmrahSüngü I added an example.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have just seen the example you posted. So no matter the case, I should be allocating on the heap, as far as I understand

Comment: @HasanEmrahSüngü Yes. Dynamic storage is usually required to store polymorphic objects.

Comment: Thanks again for the detailed explanation. I also had a very similar approach using smart pointers, but I did not want to allocate on the heap (as the Container class is already allocated on the heap and wanted to piggy back on it).